# xcode 7.2 ios 9 - Cannot get framework headers to be used unless with absolute path

Tags: ios, xcode, header, frameworks

Tried to use framework with header file but it can't find it. Finally tried using absolute path to header file inside framework to get to work.  Does anyone know why this happens.

## import BCSALib/BCSALib.h

versus...

## import "/Users/xxx/Documents/DEVELOPMENT/BCSALib/Archive/Release/BCSALib.framework/Headers/BCSALib.h"